# Items remain in the lists even after using del statement

Tags: python, django

I'm building an app using Python and Django and I'm facing a problem with some variables.

Below are simplified portions from my code to explain the problem (you can access the complete code in the [repo](https://bitbucket.org/oussama-he/db_project/src/upload-func/project/core/)):

```py
# resources.py
class HREmployeeResource(ModelResource):
  
    def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        row_result.employee_code = row.get('Employee Code')
        if not kwargs.get('dry_run'):
            import_type = row_result.import_type
            employee_code = row_result.employee_code
            instance = kwargs.get('instance')
            # we need the ones belong to these 2 companies in the report
            if instance.company in ['Company 1', 'Company 2']:
                self.report.setdefault(import_type, []).append(employee_code)

# views.py
import gc
from resources import HREmployeeResource

def import_hr_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hr_file = request.FILES['hr-file']
        data = get_import_data(hr_file)
        hr_resource = HREmployeeResource()
        result = hr_resource.import_data(data, dry_run=True)
        if not result.has_errors():
            result = hr_resource.import_data(data, dry_run=False)
            ImportStatus.objects.create(
                date=timezone.now(),
                status='S1',
                data=hr_resource.report
            )
            del result, hr_resource, data
            gc.collect()
            return redirect('core:import-report')
    return render(request, 'core/upload-hr-file.html', {})
```

The `ModelResource` class is from a third-party library called `django-import-export` and the `import_data` method belongs to this class, you could find the code of the method [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/f226bcf93ed8e1396c1c8f0a0238a574dae92662/import_export/resources.py#L720).

When I run the view `import_hr_file` for the first time everything is working fine, but when I execute it the second time I find that the old items still exist in the lists of the `report` dict of the instance of `HREmployeeResource` class.

Originally I'm using these two lines (below) to free up the memory after the import process.

```py
del result, hr_resource, data
gc.collect()
```

But the memory is not freed, and now I found this problem (the old items of the previous run remain every time I run the view `import_hr_file`)

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: `del result` will just delete the reference to the object

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych yes, you're right, but the `result`, and `hr_resource` variables should be destroyed after the first run of the `import_hr_file` function so when we run it for the nd time we shouldn't find the old items of the lists, right?

Comment: As I said, it just deletes the reference to the object. If there is another reference to it somewhere, the object will not be deleted. I don't know what `result` and `hr_resource` are exactly. But `del result, hr_resource, data` in your case wouldn't do anything (It would just delete local references)

Comment: You can use https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/muppy.html to find where else references are being held to an object, thus preventing it from freed.